# Location is shown 0.0 in iPad and iPod

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, ipod-touch

Hello What is the best way to get the location on the iPad, iPod as well in iPhone.

I have integrated the following but I'm still not able to get the correct current location.
On iPod I only get the location for the first time:

```c
+ (GPS*)get 
{
    if (!g_) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Creating instance of GPS!");
        g_ = [GPS new];
    }
    return g_;
}

@synthesize manager;

- (id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    //Setup the manager
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if (!manager) 
    {
        return nil;
    }
    manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    manager.delegate = self;

    if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) 
    {
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    }
    if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    NSLog(@"Start Tracking");

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
 }

-(void)stop
{
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%f : %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    //[self writeToFile];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager - didFailWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"domain:%@", [error domain]);
    //NSLog(@"code:%i", [error code]);
    //[self writeToFile];
}
```

Comment: I am using  8.4 in my device

Answer (score 0):

There's a location authorization issue on iOS8. Per your recent comment that you're using iOS 8.4, that might be your problem. So try this below code before `startUpdatingLocation`:

```
// This part was added due to a location authorization issue on iOS8
// See more at: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/
if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; //?
```

Prior to this, please make sure you set up **Info.plist** correctly by adding one or both of the following keys to it:

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription